# SSRS returning different results than the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a stored procedure that I can call from Management Studio and it returns 56 rows consistently.  However, when I execute the query under from inside of ssrs 2008, I get back 61 rows.  The stored procedure uses cursors and has some print statement inside of it.

Thanks,

Comment: Does the procedure have parameters?

Comment: In my case, yes (I'm having the same issue, but in reverse - not enough records when run from SSRS), but am supplying the same params in both places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I had an a stored procedure return warnings messages.  It caused problems returning inconsistent results just in my SSRS dataset/report.  I set ansi-warnings to off and my problem went away.  You may want to comment out your print statements and try that.

Thanks, 
     Steve

Comment: Where do you set asni warnings off?

Comment: ansi, that is (not ansi, or antsy)

Comment: You can do it in the command window "ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF;  
GO" or you could right click on database->properties -> options Ansi NULL Default.  Set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

I would do two things.

1. Check that the SSRS report is not using cached data - it often does.
2. If that doesn't help... within your SP write to a table in the DB the params coming in and the data being output. That should point you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, I was trying to pass null as the value of a parameter to a stored procedure. It seemed that no matter what I tried SSRS was using 'null' which did not work with @Parameter is null inside the stored procedure.

I created a report parameter, called @Rs_null, with a default value of (null). I could then use that.

(Creating a report variable was no good since I could not pass that a stored procedure parameter.)

See also [How to use stored proc with null parameters in SSRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568755/how-to-use-stored-proc-with-null-parameters-in-ssrs)